# How to copy and move rows of data in one column into another column

Tags: r, rows

R programming language how to copy and move rows of data in one column into another column

Above was my Google Search Keywords, and here are the links I have been searching, researching, and attempting to perform, with no luck. The closest I have come to, was moving one row of data from one column into the preferred "room" column, however, it removed all the "room" data.

I also thought I should write a function for the "Unit_Code" to pull the corresponding "room_XXX" data, however, I do not know if that's needed. I just need to pull the "room_XXX" data into the Empty "room" column cells that are "NA" in R.

1.) The link looks like what I think I need, however, tried to follow Frank's (User:1191259) explanation of "How it Works", and got lost.
[Filling "implied missing values" in a data frame that has varying observations per time unit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42165742/filling-implied-missing-values-in-a-data-frame-that-has-varying-observations-p)

2.) I attempted this link, however, I only tried with one column, and could not get all the other columns into a function:

```
ROOMS$room <- ROOMS$room[match(ROOMS$room_8_5s = 560:592, ROOMS$room_8_5s == 560:592)]
```

[Fill in data frame with values from rows above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10554741/fill-in-data-frame-with-values-from-rows-above)

3.) I could not follow this link, and how to write a function:
[r - fill columns in data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38064415/r-fill-columns-in-data-frame)

Look forward to any assistance, as I have been at this for almost a week, and it should be easy, however, I cannot figure it out.

```
----------
room  room_8_5s unit_code
                2
1701            1
               15
     560        8
566             8
562             8
561             8
560             8
2513           13
2512           13
2511           13

---------
```

DESIRED TABLE OUTCOME/RESULTS: Have "room_xxx" data either copied or moved into "room" column. There are up to 10 more "room_xxx" columns, this is an abbreviated version:

```
room    room_2_6ne  room_8_5s   room_13_5n  unit_code
2501                            2501        13
                                             7
                                             6
                                             4
                                             3
1601    1601                                 2
1701                                         1
                                            15
560                 560                      8
566                                          8
565                                          8
564                                          8
```

---

Here is the process of the data:

- 1. Data gets pulled from a survey site.
- 2. After user enters Unit Code, ie, 1,2,3,4...
- 3. The Corresponding Room #'s choices appear, ie, Unit Code = 2, room_2_6ne = 1601-1632.
- 4. User chooses room #1601.
- 5. In R, I pull all the data from the site.
- 6. Desired Result: Copy and/or Move the Room #'s, ie, room_2_6ne into the "room" column.
- 7. Afterwards, in R, off-load .csv reports per Unit Code, WITH ONLY the "room" Column, and WITHOUT the corresponding Room Columns, ie room_2_6ne, including all other 60 pertinent columns (not listed here for brevity), for manual checking/verification by the Unit Manager.
- 8. After manual checking, and errors corrected, in the site, I download the corrected data
- 9. Save the data, and re-paste it to another Excel 3rd Party Worksheet.

TO: E. Brown - Contributor
Here is what I did to get it to work:

48 Columns re-arranged, and then Added a Column called "rooms" after col. #4, next to the "room" column, which now = 49 Columns:

```
all <- data.frame(all[, c(1, 8:20, 2:7, 21:29, 31, 33, 35:51)])
all <- add_column(all, rooms = '', .after = 4)
```

Then ran the function with new Col. #5 - "rooms", and pointed all the data to fill Col #6 - "room".

```
for (i in 5:length(all[,5])) {
all$room[i] <- all[i,6:15][!is.na(all[i,6:15])]
```

(I'm terrible at making the column headers line up below, how do you do it here? I'm adding four spaces, and the data columns are correctly responding...)

```
rooms room room_1_7ne room_2_6ne room_3_5ne room_4_4n...
    2401                2401                    
    1501            1501                        
    1601        1601                            
    1701    1701                                
    567                                 
    568                                 
    569
```

See Image Link Here for the spreadsheet:
[ROOM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4zEm.png)

If I tried to point the data to Col #5 "rooms", it did not fill the first 4 rows of data (see under Column - "room" for Room 567, 568, 569, 571). I pasted the "room_XXX" data at the top to show that it did fall into the "rooms" column. What am I missing here that it will not fill the first 4 rows of data into the "rooms" column?:

```
rooms   room    room_1_7ne  room_2_6ne  room_3_5ne  room_4_4n...
660 660                                 660
2501    2501                                2501    
560 560                         560     
1201    1201                        1201            
2301    2301                    2301                
2401    2401                2401                    
1501    1501            1501                        
1601    1601        1601                            
1701    1701    1701                                
    567                                 
    568                                 
    569                                 
    571                                 
572 572
```

See Image Link Here for the spreadsheet:
   [ROOMS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Myyyh.png)

Comment: Hi, can you show your expected outcome for your example data please.

Comment: room room_2_6ne room_8_5s room_13_5n unit_code
    2501   2501 13
        7
        6
        4
        3
    2501 2501   2
    1701    1
        15
    560  560  8
    566    8
    565    8
    564    8

Comment: Ah, I don't know how to answer correctly in here...

Comment: Hi, I just edited and updated my original post with the DESIRED OUTCOME/RESULTS Table.

Comment: I can't understand the logic of how you generated the desired output.  Please explain clearly in step by step, how you arrived at the desired output.  Also, please add some example data using `dput`

Comment: thanks for the update @TV, but as dww notes is still unclear how you get the outcome from the input dataframe. Can you try to explain it in words. [ps is this along the lines of what you want: `temp <- with(dat, room* model.matrix(~ 0 + factor(unit_code))) ;
colnames(temp) <- paste("room", sort(unique(dat$unit_code)), sep="_")`]

Comment: Hello User dww and user20650, I did try the "temp" function, and received the following error:
Error in with(dat, room * model.matrix(~0 + factor(unit_code))) : 
  object 'dat' not found

I had to manually create the preferred data outcome in my first post, and how Marian Minar, in the thread below, is the desired data outcome. However, I tried Marian's function(s), and received errors.

Comment: Per your request, here is the process of the data: 1.) Data gets pulled from a survey site. 2.) After user enters Unit Code, ie, 1,2,3,4... 3.) The Corresponding Room #'s choices appear, ie, Unit Code = 2, room_2_6ne = 1601-1632. 4.) User chooses room #1601. 5.) In R, I pull all the data from the site. 6.) Desired Result: Copy and/or Move the Room #'s, ie, room_2_6ne into the "room" column.

Comment: 7.) Afterwards, in R, off-load .csv reports per Unit Code, WITH ONLY the "room" Column, and WITHOUT the corresponding Room Columns, ie room_2_6ne, including all other 60 pertinent columns (not listed here for brevity), for manual checking/verification by the Unit Manager.8.) After manual checking, and errors corrected, in the site, I download the corrected data, and 9.) Save the data, and re-paste it to another Excel 3rd Party Worksheet.

Comment: Hello again, reading your previous request for how I got my final output, I just manually pasted my desired output. I could not find any solution to achieve what I wanted, which looks like Marian's output below in the post. Hope that is understandable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this simple loop will do what you want, which I think is to find the single non-NA value from a number of columns and create a new column with all the non-NA values.

Sample data:

```
col1 <- c(1, NA, NA, NA)
col2 <- c(NA, 2, NA, NA)
col3 <- c(NA, NA, 3, NA)
col4 <- c(NA, NA, NA, 4)
merged <- c(NA,NA,NA,NA)
all <- data.frame(merged, col1, col2, col3, col4)
```

Sample solution:

```
for (i in 1:length(all[,1])) {
    all$merged[i] <- all[i,2:5][!is.na(all[i,2:5])]
}
```

Comment: Hello E. Brown,

I tried the function, and changed the columns to 1:51, as I have 51 columns and received this error:

for (i in 1:length(all[,1])) {
+   all$room[i] <- all[i,1:51][!is.na(all[i,1:51])]

Comment: Looks like you pasted the line of code not an error, so I can't see what went wrong. Make sure the column you want to store the information isn't in the 1:51. I put the storage column as 1, which is why the range in the example is 2:5. Another issue I can foresee is if your data has some cases where there are multiple columns with a non-NA value, you'll have to adjust the code to take the first one, for example.

Comment: THIS WORKS!!! See what I edited above - At first, I was trying 6:51, however, I know I deleted three columns, in my previous column re-arranging, which now = 48 columns, and now see it. I posted the results, sorry, I don't know how to make the column headers line up to the data columns...

Comment: Hi, tried to edit the post of edits, could not, the columns in the function SHOULD READ 6:14, not 6:48, I only need those nine (9) "room_XXX" columns to fill in the "room" column.

Comment: Tried to re-run function: for (i in 5:length(all[,5])) {
  all$room[i] <- all[i,6:14][!is.na(all[i,6:14])]
} ... Received this error now: Error in all$room[i] <- all[i, 6:14][!is.na(all[i, 6:14])] : 
  replacement has length zero

Answer (score 0):

`library(tidyverse)`

If your data frame is:

```
> df
# A tibble: 12 x 5
    room room_2_6ne room_8_5s room_13_5n unit_code
   <int>      <int>     <int>      <int>     <int>
 1    NA         NA        NA       2501        13
 2    NA         NA        NA         NA         7
 3    NA         NA        NA         NA         6
 4    NA         NA        NA         NA         4
 5    NA         NA        NA         NA         3
 6    NA       1601        NA         NA         2
 7  1701         NA        NA         NA         1
 8    NA         NA        NA         NA        15
 9    NA         NA       560         NA         8
10   566         NA        NA         NA         8
11   565         NA        NA         NA         8
12   564         NA        NA         NA         8
```

... we can use `tidyr` from the `tidyverse` to gather, mutate, and spread:

```
df %>%
  gather(value_name, value, -room, -unit_code) %>%
  mutate(room = ifelse(is.na(room), value, room)) %>%
  spread(value_name, value)
```

... resulting in:

```
# A tibble: 15 x 5
    room unit_code room_13_5n room_2_6ne room_8_5s
   <int>     <int>      <int>      <int>     <int>
 1   560         8         NA         NA       560
 2   564         8         NA         NA        NA
 3   565         8         NA         NA        NA
 4   566         8         NA         NA        NA
 5  1601         2         NA       1601        NA
 6  1701         1         NA         NA        NA
 7  2501        13       2501         NA        NA
 8    NA         2         NA         NA        NA
 9    NA         3         NA         NA        NA
10    NA         4         NA         NA        NA
11    NA         6         NA         NA        NA
12    NA         7         NA         NA        NA
13    NA         8         NA         NA        NA
14    NA        13         NA         NA        NA
15    NA        15         NA         NA        NA
```

---

Try:

```
df %>%
      gather(value_name, value, -room, -unit_code)
```

Then:

```
df %>%
      gather(value_name, value, -room, -unit_code) %>%
      mutate(room = ifelse(is.na(room), value, room))
```

... to get a sense of what these functions are doing.

Comment: Hello Marian,

I tried your function(s) and received these errors:
   -> Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows (1144, 1284), (3072, 3096), (3118, 3347), (1371, 1543), (1598, 1802), (2009, 2061), (2236, 2320), (2364, 2579), (2823, 2830)
    -> Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace
* I tried to look into tidyverse.org and also found a cheatsheet here: https://github.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/blob/master/data-import.pdf

* I tried to understand the "value_name", "value" portion - am I to replace the "value_name" with: room_2_6ne, room_8_5s, room_XXX... ?

Comment: Hi @TV, can you `dput()` your data (or the portion you posted, at least) at the bottom of your post, please?

Comment: Hi Marian, I just edited the window above, and posted my results. Sorry about the large output for dput - I guess I should delete it after you see what it contains... What am I missing?